# What is the transaction isolation level in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Can anyone help explain what is the transaction isolation level in google cloud BigQuery? It does not appear to be any documents on this. We know that in other databases, e.g. sql server database, there are transaction isolation levels : read uncommitted, read committed, repeatable read, snapshot, serialisable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not much information about it, but in [this migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/teradata-sql#transactions) we can find some comparisons between `BigQuery` and `Teradata` which can give us a clue.

As its said in the guide, `BigQuery` uses optimistic concurrency control which uses no lock operations by assuming that multiple transactions can frequently complete without interfering with each other. When multiple DML transactions are performed in the same table at the same time, `BigQuery` uses pessimistic concurrency control which uses lock operations. To ensure **isolation**, `BigQuery` uses a [snapshot isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation) method.

> BigQuery helps ensure optimistic concurrency control (first to commit
> wins) with [snapshot isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation), in which a query reads the last
> committed data before the query starts. This approach guarantees the
> same level of consistency on a per-row, per-mutation basis and across
> rows within the same DML statement, yet avoids deadlocks. In the case
> of multiple DML updates against the same table, BigQuery switches to
> pessimistic concurrency control. Load jobs can run completely
> independently and append to tables. However, BigQuery does not yet
> provide an explicit transaction boundary or session.

Its also said in the guide that

> Because there is no explicit transaction boundary in BigQuery yet,
> there is also no concept of an explicit rollback in BigQuery. The
> workarounds are [table decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators) or using [FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#for_system_time_as_of).

Given that we can assume that `BigQuery` has its particular implementation of `optimistic concurrency control` and `pessimistic concurrency control` which makes it difficult for us to get more deep information.

I hope it helps

Comment: could you give the link to the Guide ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/teradata-sql#transactions

Answer (score 0):

To add to the top answer, as of mid 2021 [BigQuery supports multi-statement transactions spanning multiple tables](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/bigquery-multistatement-transactions-mercury-rising). The linked article mentions MVCC based snapshot isolation specifically.